# LocalDate from YearMonth with nth DayOfWeek

Tags: java, time, java-8, localdate

I would like to convert a `YearMonth` to a `LocalDate` with the specified `DayOfWeek`, e.g. the second Tuesday of February 2019.

The following code throws a `DateTimeException`:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY);
TemporalAdjuster secondTuesday = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);

LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(yearMonth).with(secondTuesday);
```

In order to make my code work I need to replace the last line with

```
LocalDate date = yearMonth.atDay(1).with(secondTuesday);
```

Isn't there a cleaner solution that doesn't require the use of `atDay(1)`?

Comment: N.B. You cannot use day operation on a partial date created with only year and month.

Comment: I’m afraid that there isn’t a cleaner way. At least I cannot think of one. I understand and share your objection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have found the best and cleanest (or the least poor) solution yourself already:

```
LocalDate date = yearMonth.atDay(1).with(secondTuesday);
```

The argument to `atDay` doesn’t necessarily need to be 1, but it needs to be a valid day of the month in question, so why not 1?

`with()` always returns the same type you called it on. That is, `YearMonth.with()` will always return a `YearMonth`, never a `LocalDate`. Therefore you cannot use your adjuster there.

I understand and share your objection, but what you’ve got already is the best we can do. You can and should probably wrap it inside a method with a nice name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code is almost done. The important point is for use the TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth() method you need to provide a LocalDate with day.

Your example is right, but if you want to be little bit more clear, you can change for:

```
TemporalAdjuster secondTuesday = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);
LocalDate dateLocalDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1).with(secondTuesday);
```

And put this code into a method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate localDate = getLocalDateByDayOfWeek(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 2, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);
    System.out.println(localDate);
}

private static LocalDate getLocalDateByDayOfWeek(int year, Month month, int weekNumber, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    TemporalAdjuster temporalWeek = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(weekNumber, dayOfWeek);
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).with(temporalWeek);
}
```

Here you can find the documentation about this method: [TemporalAdjusters Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html)

Comment: The OP seems to want to use YearMonth, so not sure how dropping YearMonth makes it clearer in any way.